Neural Network to Predict Max Sharpe Ratio Stock Portfolio Allocations
I am looking into building a neural network that takes in stock price data as well as other techincal indicators then outputs weights for each stock. I am stuck on how I would create the training data to input into the model for training.
I can't figure out how to correctly get the data for this
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from ta import add_all_ta_features
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)

# Define stock symbols
symbols = list(pd.read_csv('symbols.csv').Symbol)

# Function to calculate technical indicators using ta library
def calculate_indicators(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df = add_all_ta_features(
        df, open="Open", high="High", low="Low", close="Close", volume="Volume", fillna=True)
    return df

# Download and process data for each stock separately
stock_data = {}
for symbol in tqdm(symbols):
    data = yf.download(symbol, start='2010-01-01', end='2022-01-01', progress=False)
    stock_data[symbol] = calculate_indicators(data)

here is the code. I dont really know where to go from here

Well yes. I already have historical price data as well as well as technical indicator data I just dont know how to properly format this data to train a neural network to predict optimal portfolio weights

added the code to the question
